# SQL - Some result when no row

Tags: sql

I have a table (DATA), from which I would like to perform some simple math queries

```
Security    Date        Price          
--------    ----        ------ 
1       2017-08-31     130  
2       2017-08-31     150
1       2017-07-31     115
2       2017-07-31     140 
1       2017-06-30     100  
2       2017-06-30     130
1       2017-05-31     90
1       2017-04-30     85
1       2017-03-31     80

SELECT x.Security, x.Price/y.Price-1 'MONTHLY RETURN', x.Price/z.Price-1 'QUARTERLY RETURN'
FROM DATA AS x
JOIN DATA AS y
ON x.Security = y.Security
JOIN DATA AS z
ON x.Security = z.Security
WHERE x.Security IN (1,2)
AND x.Date = '2017-08-31'
AND y.Date = '2017-07-31'
AND z.Date = '2017-05-31'
```

I would like to have full table, even when there is no result (150/NO ROW)-1

```
   Security      MONTHLY RETURN       QUARTERLY RETURN      
    --------    --------------       ----------------
    1         (130/115)-1          (130/90)-1  
    2         (150/140)-1          NULL or any other data
```

Instead SQL is returning results just for Security 1 as there is no data (NO ROW) for Security 2 for '2017-05-31'. However it is not a good solution as I have data for '2017-07-31' so I would like to see them for Security 2.

Result of my query:

```
Security    MONTHLY RETURN       QUARTERLY RETURN      
--------    --------------       ----------------
1          (130/150)-1           (130/90)-1
```

Is there any way to somehow prepare a table in which I will have all the data and let's say NULL when there is no result. Please note that normally I will have 20 or 30 securities.

I will be grateful for your assist on this one.

This is my second month with SQL and it is a way better than at the beginning but I still have some issues with logic. Do you know any good literature to start with?

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (Some product specific SQL there...)

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: look up 'outer' joins.

Comment: Not so clear what you want, but from what I understood, you need an outer join . Instead of Join, write "Full outer join"  (since I didn't got exactly what you want, it might work for you to make a left or right outer join, but it's better for you to try)

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.